# panel drag and drop is not working in extjs 4.1

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, javascript-framework

This code is working in Extjs 4.0.2a
but when converted to [4.1](http://www.sencha.com/blog/ext-js-4-1-developer-preview/) it no longer works and gives an error

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'query' of undefined`

```
Ext.onReady(function() {

    var panel = new Ext.Panel({
        renderTo: divtag,
        draggable: {
            insertProxy: false,
            onDrag: function(e) {
                var el = this.proxy.getEl();
                this.x = el.getLeft(true);
                this.y = el.getTop(true);
            },
            endDrag: function(e) {
                this.panel.setPosition(this.x, this.y);
            }
        },
        title: 'Panel',
        width: 200,
        height: 100,
        x: 20,
        y: 20
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried following code that works fine with Component but not with Panel :( and throws error : Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'ensureAttachedToBody' 
`Ext.onReady(function() {

 new Ext.Component({
  constrain: true,
  title:'Test',
  floating: true,
  style: {
   backgroundColor: '#fff',
   border: '1px solid black'
  },
  html: '<h1 style="cursor:move">The title</h1><p>The content</p>',
  draggable: {
   
   delegate:this.body
  }
 }).show();

});`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently there is a bug in this version of Ext. It wont work even if you try default D'n'D for panel like this:

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
    var panel = new Ext.Panel({
        renderTo: 'divtag',
        draggable: true,
        title: 'Panel',
        width: 200,
        height:100,
        x: 20,
        y: 20
    }); //panel.show(); });
});
```

I menage to patch the code to work the way you want it, this code should work:

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
    var panel = new Ext.Panel({
        renderTo: 'divtag',
        draggable: {
            insertProxy: false,
            onDrag: function(e) {
                var el = this.proxy.getEl();
                this.x = el.getX();
                this.y = el.getY();
            },
            endDrag: function(e) {
                panel.setPosition(this.x,this.y);
            },
            alignElWithMouse: function() {
                panel.dd.superclass.superclass.alignElWithMouse.apply(panel.dd, arguments);
                this.proxy.sync();
            }
        },
        title: 'Panel',
        width: 200,
        height:100,
        x: 20,
        y: 20
    }); //panel.show(); });
});
```

As a side note I should probably advice you not to do this anyway, because you can define your own DD for panel that you can use, and even better Ext already have one defined, so you can just override Ext panel to use default [Ext.util.ComponentDragger](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.util.ComponentDragger), or in code, I advice you to do this:

```
Ext.override(Ext.panel.Panel, {
    initDraggable: function() {
        var me = this,
            ddConfig;

        if (!me.header) {
            me.updateHeader(true);
        }

        if (me.header) {
            ddConfig = Ext.applyIf({
                el: me.el,
                delegate: '#' + me.header.id
            }, me.draggable);

            // Add extra configs if Window is specified to be constrained
            if (me.constrain || me.constrainHeader) {
                ddConfig.constrain = me.constrain;
                ddConfig.constrainDelegate = me.constrainHeader;
                ddConfig.constrainTo = me.constrainTo || me.container;
            }

            me.dd = Ext.create('Ext.util.ComponentDragger', this, ddConfig);
            me.relayEvents(me.dd, ['dragstart', 'drag', 'dragend']);
        }
    }
});
var panel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    id: 'test',
    renderTo: 'divtag',
    draggable: true,
    floating: true,
    title: 'Panel',
    width: 200,
    height:100,
    x: 20,
    y: 20
});
```

Code for a `initDraggable` function in panel override is taken from current stable version of [Ext.window.Window.initDraggable](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/source/Panel.html#Ext-panel-Panel-method-toggleCollapse) method.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get it working in 4.1: you have to add quotes around the id of the renderTo element, like:

```
renderTo : 'divtag',
```

Without quotes it was looking for an undefined variable named divtag.

Once I ran that I got no errors, and then I just did `panel.show()` to render it.

Comment: i tried code as u said...here it is but still shows same error : `Ext.onReady(function() {

var panel = new Ext.Panel({
 renderTo : 'divtag',
    draggable: {
      insertProxy: false,
      onDrag: function(e) {
   console.log(this);
       var el = this.proxy.getEl();
     this.x = el.getX();
        this.y = el.getY();
   },
      endDrag: function(e) {
   
        panel.setPosition(this.x,this.y);
      }
    },
    title: 'Panel',
    width: 200,
    height:100,
    x: 20,
    y: 20
  });

  }); `

Comment: Gotcha - sounds like the quotes around divtag were an issue but not *the* issue here. Glad to see the chosen answer worked.

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion: a Window component is a specialized Panel that has a floating mixin - might be all you need.

Comment: thnx @dmitry..the prob is window allows dragging from title/header..i cannot drag window from its body..whereas in case that i have described that was working in extjs 4.0.2a i am able to drag panel from body...

Comment: do you have a 'divtag' defined in your html?

Comment: yes here is code : `<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
Ext.onReady(function() {

var panel = new Ext.Panel({
 renderTo : 'divtag',
 
    draggable: {
      insertProxy: false,
      onDrag: function(e) {
 
       var el = this.proxy.getEl();
     this.x = el.getX();
        this.y = el.getY();
   },
      endDrag: function(e) {
   
        panel.setPosition(this.x,this.y);
      }
    },
    title: 'Panel',
    width: 200,
    height:100,
    x: 20,
    y: 20
  });
  //panel.show();

  });
  </script>

<body>

<div id='divtag'>
</div></body></html>`