# Sencha Ext JS 4 trouble getting drag&drop to work properly

Tags: drag-and-drop, extjs4, extjs

I'm attempting to learn extjs 4 and I've been struggling with drag and drop for the past couple of days. I've attempted to build a simple application with a viewport and 1 panel. I've set the panel to be draggable: true and the viewport to be a dropzone. When I try and drag the panel around the viewport it jumps erratically.

This is a short video clip of the behavior:
http://youtu.be/6WRf5j_CAR0

These are my two files:
app.js

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled: true
});

Ext.application({
    name: 'CS',

    appFolder: 'ccms/app',
    autoCreateViewport: true,

    controllers: [
    //    'TestCreator',
       //    'Primary',
    //    'Manager'
    ],

    launch: function(){

        var viewport = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('viewport');

        if(viewport.length > 0)
            viewport[0].add([{
                xtype: 'panel',
                width: 300,
                height: 300,
                draggable: true
            }]);

    }
});
```

Viewport.js

```
Ext.define('CS.view.Viewport', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Viewport',
//    layout: 'fit',

    listeners: {
        render: function(sender){

            console.log(sender);

            sender.dropZone = new Ext.dd.DropZone(sender.container, {

                getTargetFromEvent: function(e) {

                    console.log('getTargetFromEvent');

                    var temp = {
                        x: e.getX() - this.DDMInstance.deltaX,
                        y: e.getY() - this.DDMInstance.deltaY
                    };

                    console.log(temp);
                    return temp;

                },

                // On entry into a target node, highlight that node.
                onNodeEnter : function(target, dd, e, data){
                //    Ext.fly(target).addCls('my-row-highlight-class');
                },

                // On exit from a target node, unhighlight that node.
                onNodeOut : function(target, dd, e, data){
                //    Ext.fly(target).removeCls('my-row-highlight-class');
                },

                onNodeOver : function(target, dd, e, data){
                    return Ext.dd.DropZone.prototype.dropAllowed;
                },

                onNodeDrop : function(target, dd, e, data){

                    console.log('onNodeDrop');
                    data.panel.setPosition(target.x, target.y, true);
                    return true;

                }
            });



        }
    }

})
```

**index.html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Cobar Systems Continuity Suite</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://themis.dev/ccms/resources/css/ext-all.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://themis.dev/ccms/extjs/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://themis.dev/ccms/app.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone tell me what is going on?

I've tried this with Ext JS 4.07 and the 4.1 Beta, same results

Comment: I answered [similar question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8558564/panel-drag-and-drop-is-not-working-in-extjs-4-1). Maybe it can help you too (at least as a guide line).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to Change your Panel to DOM element though Panel is a component

```
listener: {
render: function (panel) {
    var PanelEl = Ext.get(panel.id);
    sender.dropZone = new Ext.dd.DropZone(PanelEl, {
             //...
        }
    }
```